# How can I obtain a DataTemplate's x:Key in code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a DataTemplate that uses a x:Key to identify itself, like so:

```
<DataTemplate 
    x:Key="myTemplate
    >
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

In some other C# code, I have a reference to this DataTemplate, but actually want to retrieve the DataTemplate's x:Key.

Question:

Is there a way to retrieve a DataTemplate's x:Key from a DataTemplate, in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it iterating over all the resources and checking their Key.

```
public static string GetResourceInDictionary(ResourceDictionary dictionary, object item)
{
    return (from DictionaryEntry key in dictionary
            where key.Value == item
            select key.Key.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then use it with:

```
string resourceKey = GetResourceInDictionary(this.Resources, myResource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var key in this.Resources.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```